# losing focus() on cordova with angularjs

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova

I have the following HTML markup:

```
 <button ng-click='focusKeyboard()'>focus keyboard</button>
 <input type='text' id='keyboard' />
```

and my javascript looks like this:

```
$scope.focusKeyboard = function(){
    document.getElementById("keyboard").focus();
}
```

The problem is that as soon as the #keyboard element gets the focus, and the virtual keyboard appears and then suddenly disappears, as if the focus has been lost just after the focus() event has been dispatched.

I am using cordova 3.4.0 on iOS 7.0.3

Has anyone had the same issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue with ng-click combined with angular-ui. The 'touchend' event was firing prematurely and closing the keyboard (input field loses focus, keyboard closes)

here's the issue reported on the angular project:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6432

and here's the issue **with the** solution using a directive on the angular-ui project:

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2017

Answer (score 0):

I have found the ugliest workaround I ever came up with:

```
        var kbd = document.getElementById("keyboard");

        kbd.addEventListener('click', function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                kbd.focus();
            }, 400);
        });

        kbd.click();
```

It does work and yes, it is really bad, as any timeout less than 400 does NOT work, which leads me to think that the ms value changes on every device.